# What is this design called and how to do it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, 3d, image-editing, graphic-styles

Recently I came across few images which I liked but not sure what there are called and how there are created. Which software is used?

If possible please provide tutorial Blog as well for my reference.

PFA,
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown illustrations seem to have 3D content, but the used projection is a special case which makes building the compositions relatively easy even in a 2D drawing program. We call it "isometric". Works which apply intensively that projection can be called "isometric designs".

Illustrator has 3D effects which generate easily the apparent thickness to those extruded parts. One can with them create with zero effort the shadings (=light and shadow variations on the surfaces). It's an easy alternative for inserting manually gradients on curved parts. Also mapping images on the surfaces is easy if the extruded shapes have straight or only simple curved surfaces.

Extruded parts with proper surface images, when rendered in isometric projection, are ready to be tiled to a composition.

Here's an elementary example of extruding a shape and mapping a couple of images on the surfaces.

[image]

The mapped shapes are preset symbols, but any images and texts will go

No 3D effect is a must. One can well get consistent line and surface directions by drawing into an isometric grid and having snap to grid ON. As well one can apply certain skewing and rotation angles and scaling to turn any straight on the face image to exactly fitting image on a planar surface of an isometric design. The needed transformations are fixed and easy to learn.

Affinity Designer has a special isometric drawing mode which generates the isometrically tilted view automatically as one draws on a straight plane. It accelerates the drawing process, but using it is not a must.

The 3rd program I want to mention is Inkscape. It's a free vector drawing application. Volunteer developers have built it gradually since 2003. The development principle makes it a little irregular, which probably is annoying for a beginner.

**To learn:** Search for isometric design tutorials. You'll find plenty of them - as well general ones as ones which concentrate to a certain program or trick.  Here's a screenshot of one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. Term isometric gives all results.